# Verify why a thing of if this proof is right

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, alternative-proof

I want to prove (convincing myself), why is this rght. In the proof of the lemma

suppose $G$ is a finite abelian $p$-group, and let $C$ a cyclic subgroup of maximal order, then $G=C\oplus H$ for some subgroup $H$

at http://torus.math.uiuc.edu/jms/m317/handouts/finabel.pdf

they have that since $H\cap(C+K)= K$, we have $H\cap C=\{e\}$. But how do they have **the part of** $H\cap(C+K)= K$? is because they say that $H'$ is the preimage of a certain map, then they can do the following:

$G/K= (C+K)/K \oplus H/K$

**but I do not know if that is enough to justificate that step, or how can they have the conclusion that**  $H\cap(C+K)= K$**,and well the part that** $H\cap C=\{e\}$ **is obvious from here,** a**nd in the proof of the same lemma they say that because** $K$ **has prime order then** $K\cap C=\{e\}$,  **is that the only reason? Can someone prove those things please is because I don't see why is that true with the arguments presented in that proof. Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Why do no one answers?, Is there something wrong with my question?

Comment: thanks for the upvote :) I appreciate it